# How to get unity particles to move closer to a line over time, to create a flame effect?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx15M.png

How can I get particles to spawn in a sphere, then move closer to the Y origin line as they move? I want to get a flame effect.

https://s3.envato.com/files/2472658/Fire_Flame_Preview_Image.jpg

Note how the flame in the middle goes higher. I want to replicate that. (Not replicate the image exactly, just achieve that 'air column' effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just fake it, with a sizable density of particles travelling upwards, then you simply reduce the size over lifetime.

I know youtube videos are shunned on here. But [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qShjsxopbfQ) video is a good start.

If you wanted more control over the origin line, Unity still exposes the particlesystem through script.

Comment: Yeah, just used the size curves to emulate the effect. It isn't perfect, but performs well enough. I'd rather stick with that than dive into scripts and try to fix it.

Comment: I guess the realism would depend on the application, but i assume you're not re-making james cameron's avatar.